# imagebutton imageurl not rendering output in src

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

Thanks for taking the time to read this.

I'm looking to do the following, however it's not rendering any output in the src param:

```
<asp:ImageButton ID="btnSearch" runat="server" ImageUrl='<%# String.Format("{0}/structure/search_icon.png", MIS.BLL.CommonBLL.Settings.SiteImageURL)%>' CssClass="search_button" />
```

The SiteImageURL is a column from the Settings row.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks again.

Comment: If I add, Page.Databind the above works, but I'm not sure why and ideally I don't want to do this...

Comment: You could do `btnSearch.DataBind()`. That call would only affect the ImageButton. I don't know if there is a way to get what you want without calling `DataBind` somewhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK so figured this out myself, used a expressionbuilder to generate my own method.

```
CustomBuilder.vb

Namespace test


    Public Class CustomBuilder
        Inherits ExpressionBuilder

        Public Overrides Function GetCodeExpression(entry As BoundPropertyEntry, parsedData As Object, context As ExpressionBuilderContext) As CodeExpression
            Dim type1 As Type = entry.DeclaringType
            Dim descriptor1 As PropertyDescriptor = TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(type1)(entry.PropertyInfo.Name)
            Dim expressionArray1 As CodeExpression() = New CodeExpression(0) {}
            expressionArray1(0) = New CodePrimitiveExpression(entry.Expression.Trim())

            Dim temp As [String] = entry.Expression
            Return New CodeCastExpression(descriptor1.PropertyType, New CodeMethodInvokeExpression(New CodeTypeReferenceExpression(MyBase.[GetType]()), "GenLink", expressionArray1))
        End Function

        Public Shared Function GenLink(link As [String]) As [String]
            Return String.Format("{0}{1}", CommonBLL.Settings.SiteImageURL, link)
        End Function

    End Class
End Namespace

Web.config
    <compilation debug="true" strict="true" targetFramework="4.0">
      <expressionBuilders>
        <add expressionPrefix="GenLink" type="test.CustomBuilder"/>
      </expressionBuilders>      
    </compilation>

page
<asp:ImageButton ID="btnSearch" runat="server" ImageUrl="<%$ GenLink:/structure/search_icon.png %>" CssClass="search_button" />
```

Works a treat! hope this helps someone else...